# Suppress PHP filemtime() errors when a file does not exist

Tags: php, error-handling

We generally don’t want to suppress PHP errors, but in this specific situation we’d like to. We cache results from complex queries, so we can avoid hitting the database too hard. When reading back from the cache, we check that the file (a) exists, and (b) isn’t too old. Sometimes that second check fails because the file has ceased to exist in the meantime.

```php
$file = self::getFile($name);
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    return;
}

$modtime = @filemtime($file);
if (!$modtime) {
    // Looks like the file has been deleted since the file_exists() call,
    // even though that was just a couple of lines ago.
    return;
}

if (($modtime + $expires) < time()) {
    self::delete($name);
    return;
}
```

However, even with the at sign on `@filemtime`, we still get errors reported occasionally:

> filemtime(): stat failed for /tmp/websites/cache/example.com/7f93434/products-data.aaa5df0c1d251a494234b3525b280eca.cache

Should the `@filemtime()` not suppress the error? Is there any way I can stop these error reports coming in?

Comment: You can check the existance of file by using `file_exists(path);`

Comment: @Sinto. Yes. I am. Please read the code.

Comment: Why not: `file_exists($file) ? filemtime($file) : false` then?

Comment: @Rafael That should be handled by the `if` before. As I see it it should only hit `$modtime = @filemtime($file);` if a file exists.

Comment: I agree @kerbohlz, but the OP stated *Sometimes that second check fails because the file has ceased to exist in the meantime*, so that would force the test again (redundantly IMO), but the error wouldn't be displayed, I believe.

Comment: Just wondering here, why does the `@` actually **not** surpress the error? Which seems to be the main question too, by the way.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I did read the code, and I did read the question, and I understood that *"Sometimes that second check"* is a reference for **$modtime = @filemtime($file)**, is this incorrect?

Comment: @Loek. I found an answer to that question. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `@` *does* suppress the error, but our custom error handler was ignoring that fact. Custom error handlers are still called for suppressed errors.

So our custom error handler had to be tweaked to allow for this.

### Excerpt from old custom error handler:

```
 public static function shouldIgnoreThisError(array $error)
 {
    // Stupid PHP still raises a E_WARNING when deleting a non-existing file
    // or directory, even with the @ operator. Sigh!
    $regexs = array(
       '/unlink\(.*\.cache\)\: No such file or directory/i',
       '/mkdir\(\)\: File exists/',
       '/.cache\)\: failed to open stream/',
    );

    foreach ($regexs as $regex) {
        if (preg_match($regex, $error['text'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

## Same function rewritten once I understood this:

```
 public static function shouldIgnoreThisError(array $error)
 {
    /**
     * If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler()
     * then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and
     * should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that
     * triggered the error was preceded by an @.
     *
     * http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php
     */
    return !error_reporting();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'none.php';
if(is_file($file) && is_readable($file)){
    $time = filemtime($file);
}
```